# How can I put Civi data in a data warehouse that supports OLAP cubes?

Tags: civimember

[Jon G](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/users/12/jon-g) wrote this as part of an Answer to a [Question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2253/is-it-possible-to-get-point-in-time-membership-data) about point-in-time/snapshot queries for membership data - "consider putting Civi data in a data warehouse that supports OLAP cubes. [Parvez Saleh](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/users/271/parvez-saleh) at Veda has implemented this and can probably speak to best practices." What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Here's some info: https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=36111.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean? If you want to just do some reporting you could use any toolset like Pentaho, ClickView, Business Objects, Tableau or Periscope that you can attach to the CiviCRM database. Data warehousing sort of assumes you want to do your reporting on a frozen copy of the database, which you can easily do by dumping the CiviCRM database regularly. If you use a toolset that works with OLAP cubes you will have to define those cubes in your toolset. Something like ClickView does not need that. It does however require that you know your way around the CiviCRM database.

Comment: Erik, thanks, checking out all of those tools. I did see Pentaho in action at Jon G's demo at CiviCon in Denver. I'm doing a one-off analysis of our membership data, so will use a 'frozen' copy of the data. As well, I want to create useful reports/graphs that will update in real time off of the live  database, so for example to show continuously-updated membership counts per week/month/quarter/year and the changes/deltas over previous time periods - so at a glance all logged-in Civi users can see member counts and increases/decreases by our Regions, staff person who did the sign-up etc.

Comment: My data analysis guru is a big fan of ClickView for real-time dashboards, might be worth having a look?

Comment: Erik, thanks, I think you mean QlikView, right? As in http://www.qlik.com/us/explore/products/qlikview

Comment: Yes I do JoeMcLaughlin, sorry about the typo :-)